# API GOOGLE MATRIX

Tags: php, google-maps

estou usando o seguinte método para calcular a distancia entre 2 cidades usando Google API Matrix:

```
  private function calculaDistancia () {

    $this->destino =  str_replace(" ","%20",$this->phpUtil->limpaCaracters($this->destino));


    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=".$this->origem."-".$this->estadoOrigem."&destinations=".$this->destino."-".$this->estadoDestino."&mode=".$this->mode."&language=".$this->language."&sensor=false";   
   print $url;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     

    $freteXML = simplexml_load_string($data);
    $distancia = $freteXML->row->element->distance->value;

    return $distancia;

  }
```

De fato funciona. E a url de pesquisa é:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=".$this->origem."-".$this->estadoOrigem."&destinations=".$this->destino."-".$this->estadoDestino."&mode=".$this->mode."&language=".$this->language."&sensor=false";
```

Bom, o problema é que em uma consulta tive a seguinte url de entrada:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muriae-MG&destinations=Macapá-AP&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muriae-MG&destinations=Macap%C3%A1-AP&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false)

Que retornou o seguinte:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <origin_address>Muriaé, MG, Brasil</origin_address>
  <destination_address>Macapá, AP, Brasil</destination_address>
   <row>
    <element>
      <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
    </element>
  </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Note que ele identifica as cidades mas não consegue calcular as disâncias.

Algum recurso?

Comment: porque não calcula apenas a distancia entre dois pontos no planeta? nao precisa desse API... a unica coisa que necessita é encontrar a Longiture e Latitude das duas cidade (imensos APIs gratuitos para isso) e depois usar a [**formula de haversine**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine) (imensos exemplos em qualquer linguagem) ... nao é 100% certo, pois a formula calcula a distancia de 2 pontos numa esfera, e o planeta não é uma esfera, mas é muito muito proximo...

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a Google, [nem todas as rotas possuirão rotas.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=pt-br#distance_matrix_element_status_codes)

Isso é comum de acontecer quando você pesquisa lugares muito distante ou que não possuem rodovias direto.

Não sei se chegou a testar, mas [nem diretamente no Google Maps](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/Muria%C3%A9,+MG/Macap%C3%A1,+AP/@-10.4181494,-55.7786473,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0xbcc64152334a17:0x59481656f33750cc!2m2!1d-42.3702252!2d-21.1291403!1m5!1m1!1s0x8d61e5e06b4b1a37:0x56357df330df0f97!2m2!1d-51.070535!2d0.0355735?hl=pt-BR) é possível achar uma rota, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você encurtar um pouco a busca e tentar achar uma rota entre [Belém e Macapá](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/Bel%C3%A9m,+PA/Macap%C3%A1,+AP/@-0.7100566,-50.3421895,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x92a461af84756ce1:0x570d540215864c35!2m2!1d-48.4901799!2d-1.4557549!1m5!1m1!1s0x8d61e5e06b4b1a37:0x56357df330df0f97!2m2!1d-51.070535!2d0.0355735?hl=pt-BR), verá que o Google mostra apenas um trajeto de avião.

Não sei se existe alguma balça para atravessar o Rio Amazonas, mas se existir a Google desconhece (assim como eu, rsrsr).

Se perceber bem, nem de [Ilha de Santana para Macapá existe rota](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/Ilha+de+Santana+-+AP/Macap%C3%A1,+AP/@-0.0175396,-51.1894615,12z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x929e1b4636bb1f9d:0x803f6925da1096f5!2m2!1d-51.1679643!2d-0.0706528!1m5!1m1!1s0x8d61e5e06b4b1a37:0x56357df330df0f97!2m2!1d-51.070535!2d0.0355735?hl=pt-BR). E olha que a google mostra que são apenas 15KM de distância. (nem sei se tem algo lá, kkkk)

Como você disse [em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166136/api-google-matrix/166152?noredirect=1#comment341826_166152) que queria somente o script do site e que adaptaria ao PHP, o script do site indicado é este:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var geocoder;
            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var path = new google.maps.Polyline();
            var pageLoaded = false;

            function setLatLngByInput(origem, destino) {
                if (origem == "" || destino == "") {
                    $(".div_info").hide("slow");
                    return false;
                }

                //apaga o mapa
                path.setMap(null);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(null);

                //declara as variaveis locais
                var start;
                var end;

                //obtem a latitude de origem e de destino
                geocoder.geocode({'address': origem}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        start = results[0].geometry.location;
                        gOrigemlat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        gOrigemlng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();


                        geocoder.geocode({'address': destino}, function(results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                end = results[0].geometry.location;
                                gDestinolat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                gDestinolng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                                //Calcula a rota
                                var request = {
                                    origin: start,
                                    destination: end,
                                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                                };
                                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                        var distanciaRuta = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                                        $("#distanciarota").html(distanciaRuta);

                                        var tiempo = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                                        $("#tempoviajem").html(tiempo);
                                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                                    }
                                });


                                //Calcula a linha
                                dist = Math.round(((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, end, 6378137)) / 1000) * 100) / 100;
                                $("#kmlinhareta").html(dist);

                                var route =
                                        [
                                            start, end
                                        ];

                                path = new google.maps.Polyline(
                                        {
                                            path: route,
                                            strokeColor: "#00711D",
                                            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                                            strokeWeight: 3,
                                            geodesic: false
                                        });
                                path.setMap(map);
                                $(".div_info").show("slow");

                                if (pageLoaded)
                                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#gotomapa").offset().top}, 2500);
                                else
                                    pageLoaded = true;

                            } else {
                                alert('não foi possível encontrar o destino!');
                                $(".div_info").hide("slow");
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('não foi possível encontrar a origem!');
                        $(".div_info").hide("slow");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            function setRout() {
                //obtem a string de origem e de destino
                var origem = $("#origem").val();
                var destino = $("#destino").val();
                setLatLngByInput(origem, destino);
            }

            function initialize() {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.388765859930732, -49.114726562499975),
                    zoom: 4,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                var adUnitDiv = document.createElement('div');
                var adUnitOptions = {format: google.maps.adsense.AdFormat.LEADERBOARD, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, publisherId: 'ca-pub-9874183828883904', map: map, visible: true};
                var adUnit = new google.maps.adsense.AdUnit(adUnitDiv, adUnitOptions);

                setLatLngByInput($("#origem").val(), $("#destino").val());

                var origem = document.getElementById('origem');
                var fromAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origem);

                var destino = document.getElementById('destino');
                var toAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destino);
            }

            function recalcOnLoadPage() {
                var fieldOrigem = $("#origem").val();
                var fieldDestino = $("#destino").val();

                var issetOrigem = fieldOrigem != "";
                var issetDestino = fieldDestino != "";

                var preenchido = issetOrigem && issetDestino;

                if (preenchido) {
                    if ($("#distanciarota").val() == "")
                        setRout();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#origem').keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        $("#destino").focus();
                    }
                });

                $('#destino').keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        $(".setrout").focus();
                    }
                });

                if ($("#origem").val() == "null") {
                    $("#origem").val("São Paulo, República Federativa do Brasil");
                }

                if ($("#destino").val() == "null") {
                    $("#destino").val("Rio de Janeiro, República Federativa do Brasil");
                }

                //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#gotomapa").offset().top }, 4500);

                initialize();

            });
        </script>
```

**Boa Sorte** com a adaptação. Porém, caso realmente queira aprender a utilizar a API da Google, [leia a e ficarei feliz em lhe ajudar com qualquer dúvida](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix)

Comment: Pois é. Mas o que mais me intriga é que esse site, http://www.entrecidadesdistancia.com.br/, esta usando a mesma API e retorna. Só que em JS

Comment: @CarlosRocha Esse site está calculando a distância **em linha reta** entre as duas cidades. A API que você está utilizando está calculando a distnância percorrida, ou seja, por estradas e não em linha reta.

Comment: Pois é, mas no caso se um falhar, uso o outro. Estou na dúvida quanto à implementação pois o código dele se mistura. Se eu achar exatamente o js que faz esse cálculo, então migro ele para php

Comment: Olhando novamente, ele faz sim: "A distância por rodovias é de aproximadamente:..."

Comment: @CarlosRocha Jogue no Google Maps e veja se é isso mesmo. Especificamente a distância entre Muriaé e Macapá.

Comment: No site, o cara diz\ estar usando a base de dados do DNIT. Mas não encontrei nenhuma API deles.

Comment: Quero ajuda com o php. O que preciso adicionar ao meu código (ou modificar) para passar a calcular?]

Comment: @carlosrocha nao, o codigo mostra claramente que ele apenas verifica se tem rota, caso nao exista ele coloc uma linha reta. Caso queira alguma ajuda sobre como fazer isso, aconselho a criar outra pergunta e explicar melhor. Nesta voce pergunta apenas sobre o zero_results. Sao assuntos dostintos

Comment: Se el utiliza para outra coisa, nao tem como eu saber. Porém, o codigo mostra que ele faz tudo pela API da Google

Comment: Ok, vou criar outra pergunta. Mas me responda uma coisa: Se estamos usando a mesma API, e na resposta dele tem a distancia pelas estradas também, porque o dele funcionou e o meu não? Apena por estar usando JS e eu php?

Comment: Voce esta utilizando os dados retornados de uma url. Em nenhum momento voce utiliza, de fato, a API da Google. Se você observar o codigo, vera que esta comentado algo como Calcula a rota e Calcula a linha.  Utilizando as bibliotecas que a Google criou, isso e relativamente simples.  Fazer tudo "na mao" que requer mais trabalho.

Comment: estou meio sem saber como criar outra pergunta e falar quase que da mesma coisa, tipo: API MATRIX GOOGLE PHP COMO IMPLMENTAR?

Comment: Criei outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166211/erro-ao-receber-distancia-da-api-do-google-matrix-distancia